# ICMP and ARP Forward

Tags: ethernet

I've five custom ethernet switch device in my network (custom ethernet switch include stm32+microchip ethernet switch).
They have RSTP protocole and blocking loops perfectly. But when I connect the device cascad my connection like this
PC-SW1-SW2(RootBridge)-SW3-SW4-SW5, when I start to ping my device SW3 not pinging SW4-SW1-SW5 pinging successfully but after the Root Bridge device I could not ping. When I disable the RSTP on my switch they communicate successfully. How could I found my problem, I check between SW1 and SW2 device SW1 route all ping to SW2, but SW2 couldnt forward SW3's ICMP and ARP packets. What is the reason for anybody have an idea?

Comment: Please check Ip access list , range IP and Also check arp cache list , if mac of device is not exist you have problem in layer 1 and 2 , You need Troubleshoot each item one by one

Comment: every device IP address and MAC addresses different and There is 1 difference between them.I wonder if having 1 difference. But network between just these device.  There is no another device on the network.

Comment: I notice something, when I send gratious ARP 100ms periodicly from SW3, Ping successfull why the solve my problem gratious ARP packets or its correct ?

Comment: please check it happend for layer 2 or for layer 3 is same , with command tools like mac ping

Comment: how can I check layer 2 and layer 3 same, I am using linux, sorry for the question I am new learning.

Comment: (arping 192.168.1.1 -c 1 ,  command macping )for layer 2 and ping for layer 3

Comment: Okey thank you, when I give an arp -a command I get all device and MAC-IP address correctly, but when I give arping -c 5 192.168.1.17 (this is not pinging device)
I get:  " Sent 5 probes ( 1 broadcast) Received 1 response" answer I send 5 message but received 1 reply

Comment: The interesting thing is that when I send gratious ARP periodically from the device I am experiencing, ping can be sent, but there is 1-2 packet loss in between. If I don't send gratious ARP periodically, I can't ping at all.  @MohammadRezamoeini